# TypeScript in Vue & WebStorm

Tags: typescript, vue.js, webstorm, nuxtjs3

I'm having a bit of a weird issue with TypeScript and Vue3 in WebStorm.
Currently I'm running a Nuxt3 project and have a component (using script setup syntax) - however, it doesn't seem like my WebStorm understands when typing a ref as a boolean

```js
const showModal = ref<boolean>(false); //Webstorm says this is of type any
const showSearchModal = ref(false) as Ref<boolean>; //This works and the type is boolean
```

However, you should be able to do `ref<T>` ? Any ideas to why WebStorm sees the first variable as `any` ?

[image]

Comment: Did you check the same with regular script syntax? Could be specific to it, or ide version. It's not shown that ref is imported. If it really is not then that's it

Comment: It works without issues if I do the regular script syntax without script setup :/ - However, would really like it to work with script setup as well :)

Comment: If you're sure it wasn't fixed in the latest version, this is clearly the case for the support

Comment: In your code you are importing `Ref` interface from vue, but not `ref` function. What if you try to add the function import?

Comment: @Ellrohir - That was just for illustrating this: const showSearchModal = ref(false) as Ref<boolean>; //This works and the type is boolean - That is why Ref is imported... In Nuxt, you don't need to import ref() from vue as Nuxt exposes these by default: https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/concepts/auto-imports

Comment: @envy but the question is whether WebStorm is able to infer the type without an explict import. I don't know, I use VS Code with Volar extension.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `Ref` declaration from `@vue/reactivity/dist/reactivity.d.ts` to declare the type left of assignment.

You have imported it but not used it (not sure if you need to even import it in Nuxt?):

```js
import { Ref } from 'vue'

const showModel: Ref<boolean> = ref(false)
```

Comment: I know this is working, however you should also be able to do ref<boolean>.... ref should accept a generic